# Spring Boot - There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400). Required request body is missing

Tags: java, jquery, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I created a simple Spring Boot REST service to handle posting data from my HTML page.  When I POST data everything is ok, but when I want to check data on @RequestMapping value href I see error message:

> Whitelabel Error Page
>
> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>
> Wed Nov 15 13:33:46 CET 2017
>   There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
>   Required request body is missing: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity> pl.sample.atms.web.rest.QuestionRestController.getQuestions5(pl.sample.atms.dto.Question)

How Can I check and get sent data? My code:

JS:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/questionsPost',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'post',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(scoreObj),
    success: function( data, textStatus, jQxhr ){
        console.log(data, textStatus, jQxhr)
    },
    error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
        console.log( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown );
    }
});
```

Rest controller:

```
package pl.sample.atms.web.rest;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import pl.sample.atms.dao.QuestionRepository;
import pl.sample.atms.dto.Question;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api",  method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
public class QuestionRestController {

    @Autowired
    private QuestionRepository questionRepository;

    @PostMapping("/questionsPost")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Question>> getQuestions5(@RequestBody Question myQuestion) {
        System.out.println(ResponseEntity.ok(new ArrayList<>()));
        System.out.println(myQuestion);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new ArrayList<>());
    }

}
```

Question dto

```
package pl.sample.atms.dto;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Question {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String title;

    public Question() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

Question repository

```
package pl.sample.atms.dao;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import pl.sample.atms.dto.Question;

import java.util.List;

public interface QuestionRepository extends CrudRepository<Question, Long> {
    List<Question> findByTitle(String title);
}
```

UPDATE

I changed Rest controller code:

```
package pl.sample.atms.web.rest;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import pl.sample.atms.dao.QuestionRepository;
import pl.sample.atms.dao.UserInfoRepository;
import pl.sample.atms.dto.Question;
import pl.sample.atms.dto.QuestionAnswer;
import pl.sample.atms.dto.Response;
import pl.sample.atms.dto.UserInfo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.isBlank;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class QuestionRestController {

    @Autowired
    private QuestionRepository questionRepository;

    @Autowired
    private UserInfoRepository userInfoRepository;

    private List<Question> question = new ArrayList<Question>();

    @GetMapping(value = "/questionsGet")
    public Response getResource() {
        Response response = new Response("Done", question);
        return response;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/questionsPost")
    public Response postCustomer(@RequestBody Question oneQuestion) {
        question.add(oneQuestion);

        Response response = new Response("Done", oneQuestion);
        return response;
    }

}
```

And I created new class - response:

```
package pl.sample.atms.dto;

public class Response {
    private String status;
    private Object data;

    public Response(){

    }

    public Response(String status, Object data){
        this.status = status;
        this.data = data;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public Object getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Object data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

Now I am able to see some sent data, but unfortunatelly it isn't generated and sent using JavaScript JSON, but this:

```
{"status":"Done","data":[{"id":null,"title":null}]}
```

Structure of JSON which I need:

```
"{"N":["4","4","5","4","2"],"E":["4","4","5","3","1"],"O":["3","3","4","2","3"],"U":["2","2","2","2","4"],"S":["3","2","2","3","3"]}"
```

I really don't know what I am doing wrong but I feel that I am close to solve this.

Comment: are you saying you're attempting to get both a POST and GET request?

Comment: see this link return error message for 400 (bad request) https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-ajax-example/

Comment: what do you mean by "but when I want to check data on @RequestMapping value href I see error message"

Comment: I'm completely freshman in Java / Spring. My goal is to send some data on Rest API and fetch them later (for example to generate previous state of application when user return to website)

Comment: It seems like your updated question is out of scope of the original question.  I would recommend looking into Spring Converters, and JSON conversion specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're restricting your method to just POST requests when using the @PostMapping annotation.

This is equivalent to:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/questionsPost", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

If you want to accept both POST and GET, I would change it to:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/questionsPost")
```

The value suggests a Post request -> so, personally I would adjust that to just "/questions".

**UPDATE**
Per your comment on what you're attempting to accomplish, I would highly recommend having two separate methods.  Spring will know which method to call based on if you're posting data, or attempting to get data.  And then adjust your business logic accordingly.

one method for Post:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/questions", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

one method for Get:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/questions", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```